# Prevent the duplication of attributes in child entity relationships

Tags: database-design, erd

I have a set of entities and attributes, one of them (show) is a parent of (series) and (film) and you can see the differences between the attributes that I'm required to model in this image here:

[image]

However, I need to create a viewing history entity for episodes/film. Since they're both seperate entities I thought I'd do an entity for each like the ones in the circle on the bottom right, but this leads to them having the same fields, but would hold a foreign key to its series or film depending on which history it was.

Is there a better way to model this to prevent having the exact same fields or not?

Comment: You could use one table for storing the history with a field indicating that a record relates to a film or an episode if you are worried about the same pk for films and episodes. You can also consider that an episode is also a film, so you do not necessarily have to have different entities for those either.

Comment: This is a conceptual model currently so it has no foreign keys or ID's, but in the histories, it would need a FK to the episode or film, and since doing it combined would require 2 FK's which would be a waste since half of them would be null

Also film and episode must be distinct, its part of the specification I was provided.

Comment: Which is more waste: having an extra field or having an extra table?